# Who to wait unit all data from roomdb is ready

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get all doors from room db , I use live data in Dao query and that work very well , but my app does not real want live data , I want to get the data once and it will never change so I tried to return just list from the dao but sometimes it return null , I tried async to set the value when the fun is finished but still same problem

```
 val doorList=MutableLiveData<List<Door>>()

    init {
        uiScope.launch {

            val doors = async(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.getDoors() }


            doorList.value = doors.await()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use livedata instead of mutablelivedata, please try change to this

```
val _doorList=MutableLiveData<List<Door>>()
val doorList = LiveData<List<Door>> get() =_doorList

    init {
        uiScope.launch {

            val doors = async(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.getDoors() }


           _doorList.value = doors.await()
        }
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: thank you "hope that answers the question" is zakir naik sound  , The error was the per-populate data is not finished , and without aync